# Can electronic engineering students get a job as a software engineer?

Tags: software-industry, career-switch, student

I am an electronic engineering student and wish to purse a career as a software engineer. I still have 2 more years of my degree left. I was wondering which modules should I select to improve my chances of landing a software engineering job once I graduate university.

So far these are my module choice for this academic year(2021-2022): 1- Embedded Systems: Learning C++ and designing embedded systems. 2- Digital Control: Using MATLAB/Simulink for PID controller design. 3- Electronic system design with FPGAs: Learning and implementing digital circuits using VHDL. 4- Power Electronics: Learning about brushless motors, buck converters and other high voltage machines.

The other option I have is choosing Digital Instrumentation module over Power electronics. In that module I would learn about programming in C and implementing temperature sensors in digital devices. What do you think?

Is there any advice you guys can give me which would help me land a software engineering job post graduation?(I live in England, UK)

Comment: Aren't there any programming and computer science electives you can take?  That would be really helpful.  You might even look at a minor in Computer Science or similar.

Comment: Nah there aren't any. There is a multi-threaded programming module for next year which focuses on more embedded C. I was thinking of doing a MSc after graduation but was hoping I could land a good graduate job that would train me. Learning on job I think is the best way to go? However, after about 2 years when I graduate I will be quite competent in C++ , would that help? (I already started learning C++ in my summer holiday) @jwh20

Comment: Ask an authority at your school.

Comment: Note that you'll probably end up being a good fit for embedded software jobs more than, say, web app jobs. Which is fine. If the software engineering students are all learning to write web apps, you might stand out...

Answer (score 3):

Of the choices you posted, the embedded systems is going to expose you to more programming than the others.  There may also be some value in the FPGA/VHDL class but VHDL is a declarative language instead of a procedural language that you will almost certainly use in any software engineering role.

If at all possible see if you can take any courses in data structures or algorithms.  But even if you can't take those courses, there is nothing stopping you from learning those things on your own.  Hopefully your time as an engineering student will have taught you how to learn new things.  technologies change over time so the ability to learn is among the most valuable things you can take away from college.

But one thing I believe you will find is that many positions in software engineering are looking for someone with a computer science "or other related field" background.  All you will need to do is show them that you know your stuff and you will be a serious candidate for the position.

Comment: Hi mate, what are the best recourses to learn about algorithms and data structures? I am currently learning C++ from a book, do you think text books are good?

Comment: Does your school have a Computer Science curricula?  If so, see what texts are used in their algorithms and data structures courses.

Comment: yeah my university has computer science and related courses(its too late for me to switch), I'll have a look there. thanks mate.

Comment: My degree is in Electrical Engineering but I've spent nearly my entire career doing software development of one kind or another.  There were a fair number of cross-discipline CS courses required just to get a degree.

Comment: Yes, Electronic engineering students can get jobs as software developers. However, you have to look for the right companies that are willing to do that. In addition, the more programming tools such as C#, Java, Python, database SQL, etc... you know, the better chances of getting a job you have.

Comment: Thanks @Job_September_2020